# Firebase rules using FirebaseDatabase.net

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

Using the rules below:

```
{
  "rules": {    
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "true"
      }    
  }
}
```

In realtime database I have :

```
UXub2KF5Jrekt2anvOnrxvamQFm2
  |__ Status: 3
```

where child name is the auth uid of the logged in user.

In visual studio :

```
var forAuth = await authService.getUid();
await firebase
    .Child(forAuth)
    .PatchAsync(new Users1() { Status = 1 });
    return true;
```

Using the rule `$uid===auth.uid` I get exception , using "true" instead all works fine !

Is there something I don t understand or something I miss ?

Comment: You're using an API that doesn't look familiar for Android development to me. How `authService.getUid()` implemented?

Comment: it is c# visual studio.

Comment: what specifically is "exception"?

Comment: catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
                return false;
            }
Code jumps here when using $uid===auth.uid and return from firebase is code 401 permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. Uid of the logged in user is not as a password to enter the rules , the "password" to get access in the rules is the TOKEN retrieved from the user UID, after you retrieve the token, send it back, than you can access the rules and the UID is like the 2nd password.

Explanation for the rules posted above!